# how can I make the arrow border right background colorful

Tags: html, css

I need to make the arrow of the right side colorful #2b6a83

```css
.tabordion {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"] {
  position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
}

.tabordion section {
  display: block;
}

.tabordion section label {
        display: block;
    padding: 16px 0px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #2b6a83;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 0 transparent inset;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  z-index:100;
}

.tabordion section article {
    display: none;
    left: 330px;
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 30px 30px 20px 21px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.tabordion section article h2{
    color: #2b6a83;
}
.tabordion section article:after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left:-229px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  z-index:1;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked + label { 
  background: #eee;
  color: #bbb;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked ~ article {
  display: block;
}


.tabordion section label:before,
.tabordion section label:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid #2b6a83;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.tabordion section label:before {
  top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #2b6a83;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
}
.tabordion section label:after {
  bottom: -0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2b6a83;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="tabordion"><section id="section1"><input id="option1" checked="checked" name="sections" type="radio" />
<label for="option1">Family Caregivers</label><article>
<h2><a>Family Caregivers</a></h2>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/A-Guide-for-Caregivers-in-Contact-with-COVID-19.pdf">A Guide for Caregivers in Contact with COVID-19</a>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Caregiver-Strategies-Handbook.pdf">Caregiver Strategies Handbook</a>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Practical-Information-for-Family-Caregivers.pdf">Practical Information for Family Caregivers</a>
John Ono Lennon, (born John Winston Lennon; 9 October 1940 – 8 December 1980), was an English musician, singer and songwriter who rose to worldwide fame as a founder member of the rock band the Beatles, the most commercially successful band in the history of popular music. With Paul McCartney, he formed a songwriting partnership that is one of the most celebrated of the 20th century.

Born and raised in Liverpool, as a teenager Lennon became involved in the skiffle craze; his first band, the Quarrymen, evolved into the Beatles in 1960. When the group disbanded in 1970, Lennon embarked on a solo career that produced the critically acclaimed albums John Lennon/Plastic Ono Band and Imagine, and iconic songs such as "Give Peace a Chance" and "Working Class Hero". After his marriage to Yoko Ono in 1969, he changed his name to John Ono Lennon. Lennon disengaged himself from the music business in 1975 to raise his infant son Sean, but re-emerged with Ono in 1980 with the new album Double Fantasy. He was murdered three weeks after its release.

</article></section><section id="section2"><input id="option2" name="sections" type="radio" />
<label for="option2">Alzheimer’s and Dementia</label><article>
<h2>Alzheimer’s and Dementia</h2>
Sir James Paul McCartney, (born 18 June 1942), is an English musician, singer, songwriter, multi-instrumentalist, and composer. With John Lennon, George Harrison and Ringo Starr, he gained worldwide fame as a member of the Beatles, widely regarded as one of the most popular and influential acts in the history of rock music; his songwriting partnership with Lennon is one of the most celebrated of the 20th century. After the band's break-up, he pursued a solo career and later formed Wings with his first wife, Linda, and Denny Laine.

McCartney has been recognised as one of the most successful composers and performers of all time, with 60 gold discs and sales of over 100 million albums and 100 million singles of his work with the Beatles and as a solo artist.[2] More than 2,200 artists have covered his Beatles song "Yesterday", more than any other copyrighted song in history. Wings' 1977 release "Mull of Kintyre" is one of the all-time best-selling singles in the UK. Inducted into the Rock and Roll Hall of Fame as a solo artist in March 1999, McCartney has written, or co-written 32 songs that have reached number one on the Billboard Hot 100, and as of 2014 he has sold more than 15.5 million RIAA-certified units in the United States. McCartney, Lennon, Harrison and Starr received MBEs in 1965, and in 1997, McCartney was knighted for his services to music.

McCartney has released an extensive catalogue of songs as a solo artist and has composed classical and electronic music. He has taken part in projects to promote international charities related to such subjects as animal rights, seal hunting, land mines, vegetarianism, poverty, and music education. He has married three times and is the father of five children.

</article></section><section id="section3"><input id="option3" name="sections" type="radio" />
<label for="option3">Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD)</label><article>
<h2>Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD)</h2>
George Harrison, (25 February 1943 – 29 November 2001), was an English musician, multi-instrumentalist, singer and songwriter who achieved international fame as the lead guitarist of the Beatles. Although John Lennon and Paul McCartney were the band's primary songwriters, most of their albums included at least one Harrison composition, including "While My Guitar Gently Weeps", "Here Comes the Sun" and "Something", which became the Beatles' second-most-covered song.

</article></section><section id="section4"><input id="option4" name="sections" type="radio" />
<label for="option4">Stroke</label><article>
<h2>Stroke</h2>
Richard Starkey, (born 7 July 1940), better known by his stage name Ringo Starr, is an English musician, singer, songwriter, and actor who gained worldwide fame as the drummer for The Beatles. On most of the band's albums, he sang lead vocals for one song, including "With a Little Help from My Friends", "Yellow Submarine" and their cover of "Act Naturally". He also wrote the Beatles' songs "Don't Pass Me By" and "Octopus's Garden", and is credited as a co-writer of others, such as "What Goes On" and "Flying".

Starr was twice afflicted by life-threatening illnesses during his childhood, and as a result of prolonged hospitalisations, fell behind scholastically. In 1955, he entered the workforce and briefly held a position with British Rail before securing an apprenticeship at a Liverpool equipment manufacturer. Soon afterwards, he became interested in the UK skiffle craze, developing a fervent admiration for the genre. In 1957, he cofounded his first band, the Eddie Clayton Skiffle Group, which earned several prestigious local bookings before the fad succumbed to American rock and roll by early 1958.

</article></section></div>
```

Comment: `background: red;
    z-index: -1;` to your pseudo elements ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif nice but there's a line in the middle of the arrow when I add your code to .tabordion section label:before,
.tabordion section label:after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where almost there ;) Just add the `background-color: #2b6a83` to your `:before` and `:after` elements. Be aware that an `:after` element with a position absolute will be rendered in front of the parent element. You can fix that by using a simple negative `z-index` like `z-index: -1`:

```css
.tabordion {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

.tabordion section {
  display: block;
}

.tabordion section label {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 0px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2b6a83;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 0 transparent inset;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.tabordion section article {
  display: none;
  left: 330px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 30px 30px 20px 21px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.tabordion section article h2 {
  color: #2b6a83;
}

.tabordion section article:after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left: -229px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked+label {
  background: #eee;
  color: #bbb;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked~article {
  display: block;
}

.tabordion section label:before,
.tabordion section label:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #2b6a83;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid #2b6a83;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tabordion section label:before {
  top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #2b6a83;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
}

.tabordion section label:after {
  bottom: -0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2b6a83;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="tabordion">
  <section id="section1"><input id="option1" checked="checked" name="sections" type="radio" />
    <label for="option1">Family Caregivers</label>
    <article>
      <h2><a>Family Caregivers</a></h2>
      <a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/A-Guide-for-Caregivers-in-Contact-with-COVID-19.pdf">A Guide for Caregivers in Contact with COVID-19</a>
      <a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Caregiver-Strategies-Handbook.pdf">Caregiver Strategies Handbook</a>
      <a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Practical-Information-for-Family-Caregivers.pdf">Practical Information for Family Caregivers</a> John Ono Lennon, (born John Winston Lennon; 9 October 1940 – 8 December 1980), was
      an English musician, singer and songwriter who rose to worldwide fame as a founder member of the rock band the Beatles, the most commercially successful band in the history of popular music. With Paul McCartney, he formed a songwriting partnership
      that is one of the most celebrated of the 20th century. Born and raised in Liverpool, as a teenager Lennon became involved in the skiffle craze; his first band, the Quarrymen, evolved into the Beatles in 1960. When the group disbanded in 1970, Lennon
      embarked on a solo career that produced the critically acclaimed albums John Lennon/Plastic Ono Band and Imagine, and iconic songs such as "Give Peace a Chance" and "Working Class Hero". After his marriage to Yoko Ono in 1969, he changed his name
      to John Ono Lennon. Lennon disengaged himself from the music business in 1975 to raise his infant son Sean, but re-emerged with Ono in 1980 with the new album Double Fantasy. He was murdered three weeks after its release.

    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="section2"><input id="option2" name="sections" type="radio" />
    <label for="option2">Alzheimer’s and Dementia</label>
    <article>
      <h2>Alzheimer’s and Dementia</h2>
      Sir James Paul McCartney, (born 18 June 1942), is an English musician, singer, songwriter, multi-instrumentalist, and composer. With John Lennon, George Harrison and Ringo Starr, he gained worldwide fame as a member of the Beatles, widely regarded as
      one of the most popular and influential acts in the history of rock music; his songwriting partnership with Lennon is one of the most celebrated of the 20th century. After the band's break-up, he pursued a solo career and later formed Wings with
      his first wife, Linda, and Denny Laine. McCartney has been recognised as one of the most successful composers and performers of all time, with 60 gold discs and sales of over 100 million albums and 100 million singles of his work with the Beatles
      and as a solo artist.[2] More than 2,200 artists have covered his Beatles song "Yesterday", more than any other copyrighted song in history. Wings' 1977 release "Mull of Kintyre" is one of the all-time best-selling singles in the UK. Inducted into
      the Rock and Roll Hall of Fame as a solo artist in March 1999, McCartney has written, or co-written 32 songs that have reached number one on the Billboard Hot 100, and as of 2014 he has sold more than 15.5 million RIAA-certified units in the United
      States. McCartney, Lennon, Harrison and Starr received MBEs in 1965, and in 1997, McCartney was knighted for his services to music. McCartney has released an extensive catalogue of songs as a solo artist and has composed classical and electronic
      music. He has taken part in projects to promote international charities related to such subjects as animal rights, seal hunting, land mines, vegetarianism, poverty, and music education. He has married three times and is the father of five children.

    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="section3"><input id="option3" name="sections" type="radio" />
    <label for="option3">Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD)</label>
    <article>
      <h2>Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD)</h2>
      George Harrison, (25 February 1943 – 29 November 2001), was an English musician, multi-instrumentalist, singer and songwriter who achieved international fame as the lead guitarist of the Beatles. Although John Lennon and Paul McCartney were the band's
      primary songwriters, most of their albums included at least one Harrison composition, including "While My Guitar Gently Weeps", "Here Comes the Sun" and "Something", which became the Beatles' second-most-covered song.

    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="section4"><input id="option4" name="sections" type="radio" />
    <label for="option4">Stroke</label>
    <article>
      <h2>Stroke</h2>
      Richard Starkey, (born 7 July 1940), better known by his stage name Ringo Starr, is an English musician, singer, songwriter, and actor who gained worldwide fame as the drummer for The Beatles. On most of the band's albums, he sang lead vocals for one
      song, including "With a Little Help from My Friends", "Yellow Submarine" and their cover of "Act Naturally". He also wrote the Beatles' songs "Don't Pass Me By" and "Octopus's Garden", and is credited as a co-writer of others, such as "What Goes
      On" and "Flying". Starr was twice afflicted by life-threatening illnesses during his childhood, and as a result of prolonged hospitalisations, fell behind scholastically. In 1955, he entered the workforce and briefly held a position with British
      Rail before securing an apprenticeship at a Liverpool equipment manufacturer. Soon afterwards, he became interested in the UK skiffle craze, developing a fervent admiration for the genre. In 1957, he cofounded his first band, the Eddie Clayton Skiffle
      Group, which earned several prestigious local bookings before the fad succumbed to American rock and roll by early 1958.

    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. bit can you fix the end of the arrow to be even please!

Comment: This is out of the scope of this question. I would encourage you to ask a new one for that :) I will help you on this one then +1

Comment: yes but i am getting white line in the middle of the arrow. I think it's because of the arrow have to be even.

Comment: It's not working in safari. the color of the text disappear if i add background-color and z-index